# Size of Kernel Of Marix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

Let $A$ be a real $m\times m$ matrix and $z\in\{0,1\}^{m\times 1}$. Clearly there are $2^m$ possible $z$ values. Is there a means of estimating,

$|ker(A| \{0,1\}^{m\times 1})|$

without brute force? Note that $ker(A|\{0,1\}^{m\times 1})=\{z\in\{0,1\}^{m\times 1}|Az=0\}$.

Comment: Let $e_j \in \{0, 1 \}^{m \times 1}$ be all $0$ except the $j$th position, where it's $1$. Let $k = | \{ j : A e_j = 0 \}$. Then you have a lower estimate of $2^k$.

Comment: Nice observation! I suppose there is no way of extrapolating to the full kernel from here.

Comment: Well the sorta trivial answer is to look at the values, say $r_j = A e_j$, and look at linear combinations thereof that add up to $0$.